# Group datafactories and give this whole group acces to Azure Keyvault

Tags: github, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I have a template datafactory. This datfactory has access to (and uses) a Azure Keyvault.
When I copy this Datafactory, I have to give the new datafactory access to this keyvault.

Copying is done by creating a new github-repository, copying the contents of the repository belonging to the 'template factory' to the newly made github-repository. When that is done a new datafactory is set up and connected to the newly made repository. Voila! A copy!

What I would like to accomplishe is that this ADF copy automatically has access to the keyvault.
I was thinking: can I somehow put this template datafactory in a securitygroup that has access to the Keyvault? So that, if I make a copy of the datafactory, this copy automatically has this same group and has access to the keyvault?

Or can I somehow tell the keyvault that all my factories have access to the vault?

Comment: I studied for a while. It seems no way to add a securitygroup. What about changing the access policy at Key Vault?

Comment: I was exactly hoping to avoid that but it seems it is the way to go. Pls mark this as an answer so I can give you karma ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the access policy at Key Vault.

1. You can add the data factory to the key vault manually according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal).
2. Use role-based access control (RBAC) according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-security#identity-and-access-management).